# Spring get data from html select

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to build website.
I have a simple form in HTML:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/new_product}" th:object="${webProduct}" method="post">

            <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
            <p>Des: <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" /></p>
            <p>Price: <input type="text" th:field="*{price}" /></p>

            <p>Category: </p>

            <select>
                <th:forEach th:each="category : ${categories}">
                    <option th:text="${category.name}"  th:value="${category.category_id}"></option>
                </th:forEach>
            </select>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
        </form>
```

When user click button I call the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new_product", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String setNewProduct(@Valid WebProduct product, Model model){
        //productService.add(product, "test");

        System.out.println("Value: " + product.getName());
        System.out.println("Value: " + product.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Value: " + product.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Value: " + product.getCategoryId());

        return "add_ok";
    }
```

`Name`, `description`, `price` are showing but categoryId not. Where is the problem?

Comment: Does it produce proper HTML from your thymeleaf code?

Comment: Form displays correctly

Comment: Don't you have to add  `<select th:field="*{categoryId}">`?

Comment: Name must match the name of the function yes?

Comment: I don't understand. I think that you have to directly point which field has to be responsible for the category property of WebProduct object. You have pointed name, desc and price directly in thymeleaf code, you didn't specify category though.

Comment: Yes, `<select th:field="*{categoryId}">` was repair my code. But I wonder why it must be called `categoryId` This is a reproduction of my function `getCategoryId()`?

Comment: You have to tell thymeleaf and spring where to look for the field. It's pretty smart but work it out on it's own.